# Where $ax + b$ prime infinitely often, is $ax + b - 2$ semiprime at least once?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, arithmetic-progressions

I'm trying to figure out a way to prove this:

Given arithmetic progression $ax + b$ where $a$, $b$ coprime and $ax + b$ is prime infinitely often, it is the case at least once that $ax + b - 2$ is semiprime when $ax + b$ is prime.

I'm looking for a way either to prove it, or whether an existing theorem is already known from which this would follow.

Stated another way, given arithmetic progression $ax + b$ where $a, b$ coprime and $ax + b$ is prime infinitely often, it is at least once the case that $ax + b$ produces a $cd$ + 2 prime, where c, d are prime.  The list of $cd$ + 2 primes is A063638 on OEIS.

What we know: A Chen prime is a prime $p$ such that $p + 2$ is either prime or semiprime. Chen proved in 1966 there are infinitely many of these.
There are also infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p - 2$ is specifically semiprime (not just prime-or-semiprime). Friedlander and Iwaniec proved this in their 2010 book.

Note that I'm not asking whether $ax + b - 2$ is semiprime infinitely often.  I just need it to happen once, that $ax + b$ is prime while $ax + b - 2$ is semiprime.

A more specific version of the problem is this:

Given arithmetic progression $P(P + 2)x + (P + 4)$ where $P$, $P + 2$ are twin primes, it is the case at least once that $P(P + 2)x + (P + 2)$, i.e., $(Px + 1)(P + 2)$ is semiprime when $P(P + 2)x + (P + 4)$ is prime.

The deeper problem I'm trying to show is that it is the case at least once that $Px + 1$ is prime when $P(P + 2)x + (P + 4)$ [or, said another way, $(Px + 1)(P + 2) + 2$] is also prime.  I'm trying to use Chen's theorem as a strategy to show this--- in other words, to show that $(Px + 1)(P + 2)$ must be semiprime at least once (and so, ergo, $Px + 1$ must be prime at least once) when $P(P + 2)x + (P + 4)$ is prime.  All my efforts to prove one just leads to a tautology where I must assume the other first.

Any thoughts, suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that if $a,b$ are coprime, $ax+b$ is prime infinitely often. (by Dirichlet's theorem)

Comment: Where is the Friedlander & Iwaniec result in _Opera De Cribro_? I see Theorem 25.10 but it gives prime or semiprime (with both factors at least p^(3/11)), and Theorem 25.11 is similar. Corollary 25.12 counts both primes and semiprimes.

Comment: Okay, I misread it apparently.  "Almost-prime of order 2" means prime-or-semiprime, correct?  Not merely "semiprime"?

Comment: I'm not trying to be pedantic, really, I'm not, but the way I read this: http://memim.com/almost-prime.html  "Almost-prime of order 2" means semiprime, not semiprime-or-prime.

Comment: Okay, this says "almost-prime of order 2" is prime-or-semiprime.  http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1383190

Comment: @RobertGross: I'm pretty sure _Opera De Cribro_ defines an almost-prime of order $k$ as a number with at most $k$ prime factors.

Comment: @Charles, I agree.  The context makes it clear that this is what they mean.  I don't think it affects my problem on the whole.  What I'm hoping is just to show that if there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p-2$ is an almost-prime of order 2, then we can somehow extrapolate that $ax+b$ where a, b coprime produces a prime $p$ *at least once* such that $p-2$ is specifically semiprime.  I think this is still plausible, even with the adjusted definition of "almost prime of order 2".

Comment: @RobertGross: Clearly that's not possible, given my counterexample of $a=105,\ b=2.$

Comment: @Charles, Right, that makes sense.  Just add the restriction that $b$ can't equal 2.  In the case of $P(P+2)x+(P+4)$ the $b$ value is clearly not 2.

Comment: @RobertGross: OK, so choose $a=315,\ b = 107$.

Comment: @Charles, But I also need an $a$ value that is the product of two twin primes, which 315 is not.  But I take your point.  I should go with the more specific case, not the general one.  That's what I'm really looking for, a way to prove the more specific case.

Comment: @RobertGross: Yes, why don;t you post that specific case as a new question? If $a$ is a product of primes (not necessarily twins) then there's at least a chance it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 and 105 are coprime, so there are infinitely many primes of the form $105x+2$, but there are no semiprimes of the form $105x+2-2$ since $105=3\cdot5\cdot7.$

For your more specific problem, given some prime $P$ with $P+2$ also prime, you're looking for some $x$ with $Px+1$ and $P(P+2)x+(P+4)$ both prime. These are both linear, so this is a special case of [Dickson's conjecture](http://books.google.com/books?id=i8MKAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA155). I don't believe any special cases are known.

Comment: I'm not certain it is a special case of Dickson's conjecture.  I need to show that there is one $x$ such that $Px + 1$ and $P(P + 2)x + (P + 4)$ are both prime.  Dickson's conjecture, if I'm understanding correctly, would posit infinitely many such numbers $x$.  I need just one case.  As a more general observation, it seems like a lot of conjectures ask "is this the case infinitely often" all the time while neglecting the question "does this happen at the very least just once at all?".

Comment: @RobertGross: In such problems it's typically the case that finding one is just as hard as finding infinitely many. (In any case if you restrict $x$ to natural numbers the two are equivalent.)

Comment: @Chalres.  Thanks.  That's disheartening, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I found this.  I assume that it's incorrect: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5516369

Let a and d be positive integers, a > 0, d > 1. If the greatest common
divisor of a and d, gcd(a,d) = 1 or gcd(a,d) is prime, then arithmetic
progression (kd + a) contains infinitely many semiprimes. This can
be seen as follows: If a and d are coprime then by Dirichlet's theorem
(nd + a)(md + 1) = d(mnd + am + n) + a is semiprime infinitely often. * * * I think it's incorrect because we can't say that (nd+a) and (md+1) will be simultaneously prime infinitely often.  No?

Comment: @RobertGross: Right, to say that you'd need Dickson's conjecture, as I mentioned. It doesn't follow from Dirichlet alone.